# Remove a value from hashmap based on key

Tags: java, hashmap

So, I have a `HashMap<String, String>`

```
public HashMap<String, String> frozen = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and I want to remove a value from it depending on the key. So lets say I put in these

```
frozen.put("1", "1_1");
frozen.put("1", "1_2");
```

I want to remove only one of the values, not the whole keyset.

How would I go about doing this? If you still didn't understand, this non-existing method should explain it.

```
frozen.remove("1", "1_2");
```

Obviously that doesn't exist, but that's what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you go through the API of [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)?

Comment: No, not yet. I'm quite new to Java, but would looping through the entry set work, then setting the entry value to null?

Comment: After the two `put` lines you've quoted, your `HashMap` has **one** entry in it. The second `put` overwrites the value.

Comment: HashMap keys are unique. You map has only one entry.

Comment: `HashMap` cannot contain duplicate keys. Maybe you need a different collection?

Comment: @user2704112: *"No, not yet."* The documentation should *always* be your first stop.

Comment: You could create a HashMap of Strings mapped to Lists, containing the multiple values (but from my understanding this is rather frowned upon).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the easiest solution would be to use some type of `List` as your value. In this particular case, it might look something like this:

```
final Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
final String key = "1";
map.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());
map.get(key).add("1_1");
map.get(key).add("1_2");
```

And then to remove a value given a particular key (as shown in your question), you may try something like `map.get(key).remove("1_2");`

Comment: Thanks man, went with your solution. I should have thought this a bit further. Also thanks for not being as negative as everyone else - I'm here to ask a question. :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have `put`'s parameter order inverted.  Duplicate keys are not allowed.  New values (for the same key) replace the older.  So,

```
frozen.put("1", "1_1");
frozen.put("1", "1_2");
```

produces a map with only one entry: key="1", and value="1_2".  On the contrary,

```
frozen.put("1_1", "1" );
frozen.put("1_2", "1" );
```

produces a map with 2 entries.  To remove an entry, you only need to reference its key, as they are unique:

```
frozen.remove("1_2");
```

If this doesn't ring a bell, then please be more specific in what the data structure should hold, and what not.  A few use cases would help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not possible. You cannot put in a different value using the same key. You can remove an entry using the [remove method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29), but for something you want, you can checkout something like [Guava's MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

If you really want to remove based on a value, you'll need to iterate through the values of the Map using entrySet(), and then based on the value call the remove method using the found key.

Comment: (Not my downvote) This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Moreover, this doesn't really answer the question. OP seem to already know this./

Comment: Knows this? How can you say? He's trying to put in two entries, which will fail, because he puts it in using the same key. It's not clear to me that he knows what he's doing.

Comment: So is there really no way to remove a value from hashmap? That's quite dissapointing.

Comment: No, there is a way. `remove` is the way. There is no possibility to have a situation like you describe (duplicate keys) though.

Comment: I've updated my answer. But you should first read the docs.

Comment: You are simply incorrect.  The map method put replaces the value for a key that already exists.  OP's code would have a size() of 1 based upon his two put statements.

Comment: I know, that's what I'm saying ("You cannot put in a different value using the same key)", and that's why I'm suggesting using a MultiMap. So why a downvote? Also not sure what's "incorrect" about my solution. With "it will fail" I mean: won't produce the result expected.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find a solution to such a problem is to consult the JavaDocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Find your class there (in your case: java.util.HashMap) and look for the remove method. In this case, you do not need to hand the value to the method (that would be really inefficient). To remove something from a HashMap, simply hand the key to the remove method:

```
frozen.remove("1");
```

This will remove the key-value pair `"1", "1_2"` from the HashMap.

Why will this not remove the first key-value pair? Because the `put` method overwrites any previous values. To be able to map a key to multiple values, try creating a HashMap with a String and a List:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList> frozen = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();
```

is a possible example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to map multiple strings to one key. It's possible but if you map your key to a `List`.

```
public Map<String, List<String>> frozen = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Then you can add multiple values to the same key as

```
public void addToMappedList(Map<String, List<String>> map,
                                 String key, String value) {
    List<String> existingValues = map.get(key);
    if (existingValues == null) {
        existingValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        map.put(key, existingValues);
    }
    existingValues.add(value);
}

addToMappedList(frozen, "1", "1_1");
addToMappedList(frozen, "1", "1_2");
```

Here's how to go about removing individual values from the `List`. The *boolean* returned would indicate if the `value` was actually found and removed from the `List` or not.

```
public boolean removeFromMappedList(Map<String, List<String>> map,
                                         String key, String value) {
    List<String> existingValues = map.get(key);
    if (existingValues != null) {
        return existingValues.remove(value);
    }
    return false;
}

removeFromMappedList(frozen, "1", "1_1"); // true
removeFromMappedList(frozen, "1", "1_3"); // false
```

To remove the whole key and the `List` associated with it just use the `Map` directly

```
frozen.remove("1");
```